# Is it possible to redefine something defined as xsd:element?

Tags: xml, xsd

I need to extend an element in an XSD schema.  In the original schema, the element is defined as:

```
   <xsd:element name="RemarkText">
      <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="C-Infinite">
               <xsd:attribute name="IdRef" type="IDREF" use="required"/>
            </xsd:extension>
         </xsd:simpleContent>
      </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:element>
```

All the examples I have seem regarding extensions seem to deal with extending types.  If this was originally defined as:

```
      <xsd:complexType name="RemarkText_Type">
         <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="C-Infinite">
               <xsd:attribute name="IdRef" type="IDREF" use="required"/>
            </xsd:extension>
         </xsd:simpleContent>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:element name="RemarkText" type="RemarkText_Type"/>
```

Then, I think I would know what to do.

But is it possible to extend an element, rather than a type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *redefine* tag can only be used with *group*, *attributeGroup*, *complexType* and *simpleType*.
Its not possible to use it on an *element*.

It is not possible to extend or restrict an *element* either. You can extend or restrict the *complexType* it is based on. You can then use the new type without modifying the original element definition by adding the  **xs:type** *attribute* in the xml to indicate the type *complexType* being used.

[image]
<sub>(source: [liquid-technologies.com](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/images/blogs/stackoverflow/redefine.png))</sub>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML Studio - Developer Pro Edition 7.1.1.1206 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="NameType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="Surname" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="NameExType">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xs:extension base="NameType">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="MiddleName" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="MyName" type="NameType" />
</xs:schema>
```

But then the XML needs to use the xsi:type="NameExType" if you want to use the extended NameExType.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid XML Studio - Developer Pro Edition 7.1.1.1206 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<MyName xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:type="NameExType">
    <FirstName>string</FirstName>
    <Surname>string</Surname>
    <MiddleName></MiddleName>
</MyName>
```

Using a graphical editor like [Liquid XML Studio](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/XmlStudio/Free-Xsd-Editor.aspx) makes things a lot easier though.

Comment: Well, that wasn't the answer I was hoping for, but thank you for writing such a complete answer (and with such pretty pictures)!

Answer (score 0):

The "any" element exists to help with such issues. A nice example on how to do this can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_any.asp).

Comment: Wouldn't I need to add that to the original schema? I can't change the original schema (if I could, I probably wouldn't need to extend it).

Comment: Essentially what you're doing is creating a new schema that will extend the original, since you can't change it.